# How to prove: $\bigcap_{n=1}^{k}(n, \infty) \neq \emptyset$?

Tags: proof-writing

How to prove that for every natural number $k >= 1$, the following holds: $\bigcap_{n=1}^{k}(n, \infty) 
\neq \emptyset$ ?

I know that for every $k$, all the intervals will have the intersection: $(k, \infty)$

But how do I write this as a proof?

Comment: Well, certainly $(k,\infty) \neq \varnothing$ because $k+1\in(k,\infty)$.

Comment: $$k+1 \in \bigcap_{n=1}^k (k, \infty )$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don’t need to prove that in order to answer the question: just show that $k+1$ is in the intersection. However, it’s not too hard to write down an actual proof that the intersection is $(k,\infty)$.

- First show that if $x>k$, then $x\in(n,\infty)$ for $n=1,\ldots,k$.
- Then show that if $x\le k$, then $x\notin(k,\infty)$, and therefore $x\notin\bigcap_{n=1}^k(n,\infty)$.